# Why does my react-table TdComponent is not getting the props from my state

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-table

I am working on a team project using react-table and need help figuring out how to set react-table rows to my array data.

I have an array object `students` from the Firebase database. When I print in in a console in an App.js it prints nicely all the array so I know it is imported correctly.

- What works:  Building react-table rows with using data prop dummy json file `studentsTest.json`.
- What doesn't work: Passing `students` array object to a data prop -it does not build rows.

Hovering over App component displays state: Array[29] so the state is correct `students` object at the app component level.

- TdComponent: in a table it says prop are undefined. So the prevuilt TdComponent is not receiving my props.

How can I pass my array data to this child component?

```
<ReactTable
       columns={columns}
       data={this.state.students} //- array of students, imported from database , doesn't build rows
       // data={studentsTest}    - dummy json file, works, builds rows
       >
</ReactTable>
```

Tried: Added componentDidMount() to set state to `students`. 
I tried changing my componentDidMount method, but can't quite figure out the correct way.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
import './App.css';
import NavTab from './components/navTab';
import "react-table/react-table.css";
import jsonData from './mock-data/grades.json'
import students from './Data/database'
import studentsTest from './mock-data/studentsTest.json'
import database from './Data/database'
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //students: this.props.students
      students
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('react')
    const studentRef = rootRef.child('students')
    console.log(studentRef)
    studentRef.on('value', snap => {
      this.setState({
        students: students
      });
    });
  }
```

```
return (
      <ReactTable
        columns={columns}
        data={this.state.students} //- doesn't build rows
        // data={studentsTest}    - works, builds rows
        >
      </ReactTable>
);
```

Comment: This is my students' array : {id: "yc_8_24_1@fake.com", name: "y", a1: 10, a2: 10, a3: 10, …}
1: {id: "vbtt@fake.com", name: "V", a1: 10, a2: 10, a3: 10, …}
2: {id: "YC_test@fake.com", name: "y", a1: 10, a2: 10, a3: 10, …}

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a tour around: [How to ask in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: @k3lly.dev Thank you. I did indeed read how to ask questions. Are you referring to anything specific I missed or doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Your redaction is kind of overloaded with text, it's fine to explain correctly everything and not miss a word. But the redaction like titles, separators, lists, etc can be very useful to give your question better readability.

Comment: @k3lly.dev Thank you! I just made some edits, looks more readable now I think...